# Return last vowel in string

Tags: c++

I need to return the last vowel (uppercase or lowercase) in a given string and return '!' if there aren't any vowels in the string.

The code I wrote works but only if the string ends with a vowel. If it doesn't end with a vowel it always returns a '!'.

How can I fix this?

```
char lastVowel(string s){

    char vowel = ' ';

    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i){
        if(s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] == 'O' || s[i] == 'U' ||
           s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u'){
            vowel = s[i];
        }else{
            vowel = '!';
        }
    }
    return vowel;
}
```

Comment: You don't need else part and you should initialize vowel with !

Comment: *How can I fix this?* -- You would have had a much easier time looping backwards starting from the last character, not forwards.

Comment: Another possible solution... if I told you to find the last heart in a deck of 52 cards, would you start looking from the beginning, or would you start at the end?  Similarly, if I told you to find the first heart, would you start at the end?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `vowel` to `!` *every time you find a non-vowel character* in your string. Instead, you need to simply do this:

```
char lastVowel(string s){
    // Default value is '!'
    char vowel = '!';

    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i){
        if(s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] == 'O' || s[i] == 'U' ||
           s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u'){
            vowel = s[i]; // Only set vowel when a vowel character is found
        }
    }
    // If a vowel was set in the loop, you return that
    // Otherwise, you return its default value (!)
    return vowel;
}
```

While this answers *why* you encounter that issue, and how to fix it with minimal changes to your approach, [Casey's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877173/843953) below is better because it uses standard library functions that look for the characters of interest from the end of the string -- like other commenters have said, if you care about the last occurrence of something, it's smarter to start looking in the end.

Answer (score 7):

This is really simple and can be done in two lines:

```cpp
#include <string>

char lastVowel(std::string s) {
    const auto pos = s.find_last_of("aeiouAEIOU");
    return pos == std::string::npos ? '!' : s[pos];
}
```

You could also `std::transform` the string into lowercase and shorten the search to just `aeiou`, but I haven't tested whether or not this impacts performance.

EDIT:

I just tested it. For large N (100,000 character string) using `std::transform` is about 158 times slower.

**Do not convert your string to one case or the other first. It is MUCH faster to just make the search criteria longer.**